# Filter for Key-Value pairs using Querydsl

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

My issue needs a bit of explanation. I try to keep it as short possible without missing important aspects. So already thanks to everyone who reads this through until the end.

### What I try to achieve

perform a GET request with several query parameters as filters

```
api/parentResource?areaCode=11&childEntity.kvlist.API_KEY=123CBA321
```

The example request will retrieve a list of `parentResource` that belong to a certain area AND have the key-value pair `API_KEY=123CBA321` in their child entity's list (the list itself is also a child entity of the child entity, for brevity let's call it *KV_list*).

Using Querydsl I got this working so far, but there is one thing I couldn't solve myself:

**The issue is** that querydsl probably behaves as expected <sup>1</sup> when using AND conjunctions. **What I need to achieve is, that** the filter on KV_list only returns a truthy BooleanExpression/Predicate if the actual **KV-*pair*** exists.

Example:

KV_list table contains following records:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|  id   |    key    |   value   |  foreign_key  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| UUID1 | API_KEY   | 123CBA321 | childEntityFK |
| UUID2 | KEY2      | XYZ987    | childEntityFK |
| UUID3 | OTHER_KEY | NNN       | childEntityFK |
+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

While you would expect the GET request from above to work, the following shouldn't return anything, as the KV-pair doesn't exist:

```
api/parentResource?areaCode=11&childEntity.kvlist.KEY2=NNN
```

<sup>1</sup> unfortunately, querydsl simply checks if there is a `key=KEY2` *AND* a `value=NNN` and then returns a truthy predicate.

The model looks like:
`Parent <--1:n--> ChildEntity <--1:n--> KV_Entity`

### What I tried so far

- simple conjunction of key and value:

  ```
   ExpressionUtils.allOf(this.predicate,
   QParent.parent.childEntities.any().kvEntities.any().key.eq(var_key),
   QParent.parent.childEntities.any().kvEntities.any().value.eq(var_value)
   );
  ```
- directly call eq method on KV-object:

  ```
  ExpressionUtils.and(this.predicate,
  QParent.parent.childEntities.any().kvEntities.any()eq(var_kvObject)
  );
  ```
- JPAExpressions.select().from().join()...
- several flavours of the approaches mentioned above

I'm really stuck and would appreciate any help/hints.
Thanks in advance!

---

frameworks/libraries being used:

- Spring Boot 2.0.4
- Querydsl 4.1.4

---

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont know the full context of your question.
Maybe you can create a virtual key (Hash).

That contains `var_key` and `var_value`.

Then you can use 
`QParent.parent.childEntities.any().kvEntities.any().hash.eq(hash)`
To search for kvEntities

Comment: thanks @apachemaven this looks like a valid workaround for my case